# Template specialization issue

Tags: c++

There is an error when including "x.h" below from multiple C++ source files.

```
x.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `void f(A&, B const&)'
/tmp/ccdXc4Sz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What happens here? How can it be rewritten to work?

**x.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    int x, y;
};

struct A
{
  template <class T>
  friend void f(A& a, const T& t);
private:
  int x {0};
};

template <class T>
void f(A& a, const T& t) { std::cout << a.x++ << ": " << t << std::endl; } 

template <>
void f(A& a, const B& b) { std::cout << a.x++ << ": " << b.x << "," << b.y << std::endl; }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "x.h"
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    f(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

**x.cpp**

```
#include "x.h"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specialized templated function is not template anymore, it should be treated as normal global function. So, place it to `.cpp` file, or declare as `static` or `inline`.

– answer by Alex F